# CommonJs + Browserify - Wrench.js Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, commonjs

I am trying to get setup using CommonJS for client side development. I am using Gulp to trigger Browserify to automatically compile my JS file for me. I have simply left my JS file as:

```
var commonjs = require('common.js');
```

Browserify manages to compile it fine but in the browser I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

The line it is referring to is actually coming from wrench.js which is being included as a dependancy for common.js:

```
isWindows = !!process.platform.match(/^win/)
```

If I log process.platform it returns as undefined as it claims. From reading online, wrench has been deprecated so I am surprised it is even still being used. That combined with the fact that from a search, I can not find a reference to this error, it feels like I am doing something really stupid!!

I installed common.js through npm, this is the dependancies from my packages.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "browserify": "^14.3.0",
    "common.js": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1"
  }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Am I using the wrong package or something?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this myself just after posting, but i will leave this here in case anyone else comes across it.

There seems to be several npm modules named similar to commonjs. The one I actually needed was common-js not common.js as posted above. As soon as I changed this, it started working.

Hope that helps someone else